# How to know how many remaining pages for the print job in windows 10

Tags: windows, pdf, printer, hp

I have my printer HP Ink Tank Wireless 415
And I am using It with windows 10 home I couldn't find a way to see how many pages left when printing something like "pdf" so is there a way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your printer uses PCL3 (a host-based language) which works on pages, not documents. You could check the Windows queue (click the printer icon on the task bar) to see if the byte count there can give you any idea of the number of pages already printed. That is only possible if the printer has very little buffer.

Except with the very simplest printers (with almost no buffer) the printer's count will not match Windows. Here's why.

All printers have at least some input buffer; most also have a page buffer. That makes it virtually impossible to tell from the PC how many pages are left to print: the pages may have left the Windows queue, but they are still sitting in the printer, waiting to be printed. Many of the more expensive printers can store multiple pages, or even entire multi-page documents, making this even more difficult.

About the only reliable way is if the printer itself can tell you. With the more expensive printers, which understand "documents" instead of just "pages", it is possible for the printer to tell you how far it is within a document. My home Fuji Xerox DocuPrint CM305df can do so - if the document is not too large. If there are too many pages, its display does tell me what page number it is up to, but it only adds "of nnn pages" once it has the last page in its buffer.

Comment: I did check the printer icon on task bar but it didn't tell me how many pages left it tell me only what files are printing paused etc so is there a way to know from windows?

Comment: Not as far as I know. And I just realised that the taskbar only tells you how many bytes have been transferred, not how many pages. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Ok thanks for help